# Receiving "security service 3 error parsing ScopedPDU" in trap with AES-256 as priv protocol

Tags: net-snmp, pysnmp, pdu

I am trying to receive pysnmp trap message with SHA/MD5 and AES-256. I can receive AES-128 trap but I am unable to log AES-256 priv traps. Here is the error for each PDU generated in snmptrapd.log

```
NET-SNMP version 5.9.3
security service 3 error parsing ScopedPDU
security service 3 error parsing ScopedPDU
```

I am able to log traps normally with other settings.
Here is my entry in snmptrapd.conf.

```
createUser -e <engine_id> test_user SHA "password" AES-256 "password"
```

I am able to capture packets in wireshark which gives following after entering credentials(username and password).
[image: wireshark]

Please let me know what I can change in config to log the traps.

I am trying to receive pysnmp trap message with SHA/MD5 and AES-256. I can receive AES-128 trap but I am unable to log AES-256 priv traps. Here is the error for each PDU generated in snmptrapd.log

```
NET-SNMP version 5.9.3
security service 3 error parsing ScopedPDU
security service 3 error parsing ScopedPDU
```

I am able to log traps normally with other settings.
Here is my entry in snmptrapd.conf.
createUser -e <engine_id> test_user SHA "password" AES-256 "password"
I am able to capture packets in wireshark which gives following after entering credentials(username and password).
[image: wireshark]

Please let me know what I can change in config to log the traps.